# .Sort(Function(x, y) -> re-arranges list when there is nothing to sort (i.e., all sort fields have the same value)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, list, sorting

I am using:

```
mybookings.listOfBookings.Sort(Function(x, y) x.checkIn.Date.CompareTo(y.checkIn.Date)
```

Now, this works great, but I have run into a situation which introduces a bug in the rest of my code.

When I have a list of objects like the above, and both objects' `checkIn` has the same `date` value, the sort re-arranges the list... I am expecting it to keep it as is, because there is nothing to sort...

When it swaps around the list, it introduces issues further down my code, that expects the list to have been kept as is. Yes, one can argue that I need to fix that... but in this case, there are many other factors that expect the first occurrence in the list, to be the actual first occurrence (based on other properties of the object).

In a nutshell, objects get "paid" from earliest (checkIn) to latest (checkIn) elsewhere in the software. What happens here, is that there is now an "unpaid" object at position 1 in the list, when it should be, and originally was, at position 2, for example.

- The list can have any number of objects
- The list normally has multiple objects, and it correctly sorts it based on different Date values
- The field sorted on, is a `date` type.
- I cant check positions before and after the sort... well I could, but that defies the idea of using the sort function. I can then roll my own sorting routine...(which I don;t want to do unless absolutely necessary)

Can one somehow force the sort to not re-order the list if there are no changes?

Comment: This is usually referred to as a stable sort. Most library `Sort` methods should, as part of their documentation, tell you whether they are stable or unstable. [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx): "This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved"

Comment: You learn something new every day... thanks to all participating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, **if two
>   elements are equal, their order might not be preserved**. In contrast, a
>   stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal.

You could check first if all are the same:

```
Dim first As Date = mybookings.listOfBookings.First().checkIn.Date
Dim allSameDate As Boolean = mybookings.listOfBookings.Skip(1).
    All(Function(x) x.checkIn.Date = first)
If Not allSameDate Then
    ' now you can sort '
    mybookings.listOfBookings.Sort(Function(x, y) x.checkIn.Date.CompareTo(y.checkIn.Date)
End If
```

Another way is to use LINQ to create a new `List(Of T)`, [`Enumerable.OrderBy` is stable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx):

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of doing this... My concerns were, lets say I have 5 objects, and object 2 and 3 has the same date... will it swap them around when it re-arranges 1,4 and 5?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder: if you need to preserve the order you either have to use LINQ (i've edited my answer acccordingly, use `OrderBy` + `ToList`) or you have to order by a second criterion which you've used originally when you've created the list.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using: `.listOfBookings = mybookings.listOfBookings.OrderBy(Function(x) x.checkIn.Date).ToList`

Answer (score 2):

Stop using `List.Sort` and use [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead. The latter implements a [stable sort](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Stable_Sort), in contrast to the former:

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In
>   contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements
>   that have the same key.

I 'm not comfortable with VB.NET, but in C# you would write that as

```
var sorted = mybookings.listOfBookings.OrderBy(b => b.checkIn.Date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Tim's answer was first, although he expanded on it later to add more info. +1

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using: .listOfBookings = mybookings.listOfBookings.OrderBy(Function(x) x.checkIn.Date).ToList